# How to Convert Text to Speech in PHP

Tags: php, mp3, text-to-speech

How can I convert text to speech using PHP, possibly generating an MP3 file and sending that back to the user?

Thank You.

Comment: You will probably need to run some sort of software on your server that PHP makes calls to. I don't think it's feasible to do with pure PHP.

Comment: @Sam152: You just have to save a file, so technically it is possible in pure PHP (`file_put_contents()`, `pack()`). However it would be completley pointless. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Probably following is the code as mentioned in the above link:

```
<?php
//create a random number filename so that simultaneous users don't overwrite each other
$filename = 'test.txt';
$text = 'This text will be converted to audio recording';
$outputfile = basename($filename, ".txt");
$outputfile = $outputfile . '.wav';

if (!$handle = fopen($filename, "w"))
{
    //we cannot open the file handle!
    return false;
}
// Write $text to our opened file.
if (fwrite($handle, $text) === FALSE)
{
    //couldn't write the file...Check permissions
    return false;
}

fclose($handle);

//initialise and execute the festival C engine
//make sure that your environment is set to find the festival binaries!
$cmd = "text2wave $filename -o $outputfile";
//execute the command
exec($cmd);

unlink($filename);
echo "Recording is successful. \nRecording File: " . $outputfile;
//finally return the uptput file path and filename
return $outputfile;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use macos you can simply use apple tts

```
shell_exec("say -o test.aiff this is a test");
```